# I'm trying to update my table but it keeps on giving me a required field while it's excluded from the updating

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to update the table using postman, but I keep getting this error:

> "The ImageUrl field is required."

`ImageUrl` is supposedly getting data from another `productImages` table. It's working well in the post method but not in the put method.
My product model and put method in my controller are like this :

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public bool Availability { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
        public List<IFormFile> ImageUrl { get; set; }

    }



        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult UpdateProduct(int id, [FromBody] Product updatedProduct)
        {
            var existingProduct = _context.Products.Find(id);

            if (existingProduct == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

         
            existingProduct.Name = updatedProduct.Name;
            existingProduct.Description = updatedProduct.Description;
            existingProduct.Price = updatedProduct.Price;
            existingProduct.Availability = updatedProduct.Availability;
            existingProduct.CategoryId = updatedProduct.CategoryId;
            existingProduct.BrandId = updatedProduct.BrandId;

           
            existingProduct.ImageUrl = existingProduct.ImageUrl;

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: show us your request from postman

Comment: {
    "productId":1,
    "name": "Updated Product Name",
    "description": "Updated product description",
    "price": 39.99,
    "availability": true,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "brandId": 1
}

Comment: what is the URL and HTTP method? Content-Type? did you try to put a breakpoint at the first line? did you try to remove ImageUrl if you don't need this for PUT?

Comment: The content-type is "application/json" and i did remove it but it's still the same result :/

Comment: what about other questions that I asked?

Comment: I don't understand exactly the questions, I tried putting a breakpoint in the first line but it didn't do anything, for the URL, it's an online azure Database. and the method is a HttpPut method if i got it right

Comment: id you try to remove ImageUrl if you don't need this for PUT?

Comment: I did remove it but still nothing

Comment: See if this link helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188100/net-core-5-0-web-api-httpput-(frombody)-how-to-omi